# How to access parent props from child component - react

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props, react-context

Let's say that I want to build a reusable react Accordion Component, which will have an AccordionSummary and an AccordionDetails child like this:`

```
<Accordion>
 <AccordionTitle>This is an accordion title</AccordionTitle>
 <AccordionSummary>This is the accordion summary, which will be shown if the user clicks the accordion title </AccordionSummary>
</Accordion>
```

How can I make it, so that when the AccordionTitle is clicked, the summary will be shown to the corresponding accordion. Is there a way to share data between react child and parent components for each individual accordion in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) here. Sorry for promoting, but I wrote a detailed article on this topic : https://rocambille.github.io/en/2022/05/02/how-to-do-a-modal-in-react-the-html-first-approach/

This could lead to something like that for your `Accordion`:

```js
const AccordionContext = createContext();

function Accordion({ children }) {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState();

  return (
    <AccordionContext.Provider value={ { someState, setSomeState } }>
      {children}
    </AccordionContext.Provider>
  );
}

function AccordionTitle({ children }) {
  const { someState, setSomeState } = useContext(AccordionContext);

  return (
    ...
  );
}

function AccordionSummary({ children }) {
  const { someState, setSomeState } = useContext(AccordionContext);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

But as stated in my article, you may want to consider HTML stuff like the [summary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary)/[details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) tags ;)

Comment: This is actually what I was looking. Thanks a lot for the answer and the article too.